# How to parse json settings in appsettings.json into a class in c# .netcore

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, app-config, configurationsection

I have a appsettings.json that look like this

```
{
  "AppName": "my-app-service",
  "MyModel": {
    "MyList": [{
      "CountryCode": "jp"
    },{
      "CountryCode": "us"
    }]
  }
}
```

Now, i have a POCO file, (MyList.cs is ommited, it has a single string key countryCode)

```
public class MyModel
{
    public IList<MyList> MyList;
}
```

I wish to make it so that MyModel can be injected anywhere in my code, how do I do that? I see that people do this in their setup.cs

```
    services.Configure<MyModel>(Configuration.GetSection("MyModel"));
```

How ever it looks like when I use `IOption<MyModel>` in my code in the contructors, I just get null value. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Can you please share your code that is converting the json to the model please?
Otherwise you may have to read it out into an object using Newtonsoft JSON.

Comment: @Slipoch That is the question I am trying to ask. How do I convert the JSON to "MyModel" directly through this Configuration magic?

Comment: What you describe should work (Configure + IOptions). If you want to validate that it's binding correctly you can use `var o = new MyModel(); Configuration.GetSection("MyModel").Bind(o);` and then inspect `o` which should now be populated. You might need a reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` if you don't already have it via transitive references.

Comment: Though now looking at your class more carefully, `MyList` is a **field**. The binder only works with **properties** so add `{ get; set; }` and you should be good to go

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 wow this is the biggest gotcha ever. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct: calling `Configure<T>` sets up the options infrastructure for `T`. This include `IOptions<T>`, `IOptionsMonitor<T>` and `IOptionsSnapshot<T>`. In its *simplest* forms, configuring the value uses an `Action<T>` or as in your example binding to a specific `IConfiguration`. You may also *stack* multiple calls to either form of `Configure`. This then allows you to accept an `IOptions<T>` (or monitor/snapshot) in your class' constructor.

The easiest way to determine if binding to an `IConfigurationSection` is working as you intend it to is to manually perform the binding and then inspect the value:

```
var opts = new MyClass();
var config = Configuration.GetSection("MyClass");
// bind manually
config.Bind(opts);
// now inspect opts
```

The above is dependant on the  `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` package which you should already have as a transitive dependency if you are referencing the Options infrastructure.

Back to your issue: the binder will only bind `public` **properties** by default. In your case `MyClass.MyList` is a **field**. To get the binding to work you must change it to a **property** instead.

If you wanted/needed to bind non-`public` properties you could pass an `Action<BinderOptions>`:

```
// manually
var opts = new MyClass();
var config = Configuration.GetSection("MyClass");
// bind manually
config.Bind(opts, o => o.BindNonPublicProperties = true);

// DI/services 
var config = Configuration.GetSection("MyClass");
services.Configure<MyClass>(config, o => o.BindNonPublicProperties = true);
```

Even with `BinderOptions` there is still no way to bind to fields. Also note that there is varying behavior for things like collection *interfaces*, arrays and `get` only properties. You may need to play around a bit to ensure things are binding as you intend.

Answer (score 2):

If you have some appsettings.json like :

```
{ 
  "SomeConfig": {
  "Key1": "Value1",
  "Key2": "Value2",
  "Key3": "Value3"
  } 
}
```

Then you can have your POCO as :

```
public struct SomeConfig
{
    public string Key1 { get; set; }

    public string Key2 { get; set; }

    public string Key3 { get; set; }
}
```

After this you need to put
`services.Configure<SomeConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("SomeConfig"));` entry
in `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

Now in any class where you want to use it :

```
private readonly ILogger logger;
private readonly SomeConfig someConfigurations;

public SampleService(IOptions<SomeConfig> someConfigOptions, ILogger logger)
{
   this.logger = logger;
   someConfigurations = someConfigOptions.Value;
   logger.Information($"Value of key1 : '{someConfigurations.Key1}'");
}
```